# Currency converter in Python

Tags: python, converting, finance

I am looking for some ways to make my code simpler for this currency converter.

```
currencies = {
    "BRL":"(Brazilian Real)",
    "USD":"(US Dollar)",
    "EUR":"(Euro)",
    "GBP":"(Great Britain Pound)"
}

def real_to_dollar():
    user_value = raw_input("How many reais? ")
    ammount = float(user_value)
    conversion = ammount * 0.26
    print str(user_value) + " reais is equal to " + str(conversion) + " dollars."

def dollar_to_real():
    pass

def dollar_to_euro():
    pass

def euro_to_dollar():
    pass

def euro_to_pound():
    pass

def pound_to_euro():
    pass

def real_to_euro():
    pass

def euro_to_real():
    pass

def real_to_pound():
    pass

def pound_to_real():
    pass

def dollar_to_pound():
    pass

def pound_to_dollar():
    pass

print "Welcome to currency converter."
print "Supported currencies:"
for currency in currencies:
    print currency + " " + currencies[currency]

user_choice1 = raw_input("Convert: ")
user_choice2 = raw_input("To: ")

if user_choice1 == "BRL" and user_choice2 == "USD":
    real_to_dollar()

elif user_choice1 == "USD" and user_choice2 == "BRL":
    dollar_to_real()
```

Comment: We realize you are early in development, and as such you have many empty methods; but please realize it's extremely difficult to review only the code which _does something_, let alone the unimplemented code. Just keep that in mind as you get answers.

Answer (score 6):

You might not have realised it yet, but all your unimplemented methods will very much look like `real_to_dollar`:

- ask the user how much of the original currency he wants converted;
- apply a specific conversion rate;
- tell the user the result of the conversion in the desired currency.

So that should be a single function, parametrized by the elements that differ between various calls: name of the origin currency, name of the converted currency, exchange rate.

```
def convert_currency(from, to, rate):
    user_value = raw_input("How many {}? ".format(from))
    amount = float(user_value)
    conversion = amount * rate
    print " {} {} is equal to {} {}.".format(user_value, from, conversion, to)
```

Also note the use of `format` to simplify building a string with numbers.

You would then call it `convert_currency("reais", "dollars", 0.26)` or `convert_currency(" dollars", "reias", 3.85)`.

However, having to use a bunch of `if`s to know what parameters to use (like you would have used a bunch of `if`s to know which function to call) is not that great and can be a burden to maintain and expand. You could use a second dictionary to map couples of currencies to exchange rates:

```
RATES = {
    ("BRL", "USD"): 0.26,
    ("USD", "BRL"): 3.85,
    # Expand as necessary
}
```

And just have to get the rate using `RATES[(user_choice1, user_choice2)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Exchange rates change every day, so your program would quickly become either obsolete or unmaintainable by having the `conversion` factor as a constant in the program. I suggest you to use an API (for example: http://fixer.io/).

You have a supported `currencies` dictionary, but you don't test if the user input is among the supported ones. This can be done with a `while True:` loop and then `break` if the user choice is ok.

I also believe that the user would be bummed for having to digit the currency abbreviation :p...

Taking those considerations in mind, here's an example code:

```
import requests


SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES = {
    "EUR": "European euro",
    "USD": "US dollar",
    "GBP": "Pound sterling",
    "BRL": "Brazilian real"
}


CURRENCY_CODES = {
    1: "EUR",
    2: "USD",
    3: "GBP",
    4: "BRL"
}


def get_exchange_rate(base_currency, target_currency):
    if not (base_currency in SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES.keys()):
        raise ValueError("base currency {} not supported".format(base_currency))
    if not (target_currency in SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES.keys()):
        raise ValueError("target currency {} not supported".format(target_currency))

    if base_currency == target_currency:
        return 1

    api_uri = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base={}&symbols={}".format(base_currency, target_currency)
    api_response = requests.get(api_uri)

    if api_response.status_code == 200:
        return api_response.json()["rates"][target_currency]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Welcome to Currency Converter")

    amount = float(input("Enter the amount you wish to convert: "))

    print("Choose a base currency among our supported currencies:")
    while True:
        for code, currency in CURRENCY_CODES.items():
            print("code {}: base {}".format(code, currency))
        base_currency_code = int(input("Please digit the code: "))
        if base_currency_code in CURRENCY_CODES.keys():
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid code")
    base_currency = CURRENCY_CODES[base_currency_code]

    print("Choose a target currency among our supported currencies:")
    while True:
        for code, currency in CURRENCY_CODES.items():
            print("code {}: target {}".format(code, currency))
        target_currency_code = int(input("Please digit the code: "))
        if target_currency_code in CURRENCY_CODES.keys():
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid code")
    target_currency = CURRENCY_CODES[target_currency_code]

    exchange_rate = get_exchange_rate(base_currency, target_currency)

    print("{} {} is {} {}".format(amount, base_currency, amount * exchange_rate, target_currency))
```

The code uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, which is awesome and I suggest you to check it out.